# How can you iterate over an object (associative array) in Dojo?

Tags: dojo

Does Dojo have a method similar to jQuery's `each()` that allows you to pass an object to iterate over? `jQuery.each()` allows you to pass either an array or an object. In the latter case, the callback function receives both a key and the value. Is there something that allows you to do this in Dojo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for `dojox.lang.functional.object.forIn`.

There's no actual documentation page in dojo reference, only a small example in article [Functional fun in JavaScript with Dojo](http://www.lazutkin.com/blog/2008/01/12/functional-fun-javascript-dojo/):

> Module dojox.lang.functional.object defines important object helpers:
>
> ```
> df.forIn(object, callback[, thisObject])
> ```

If you have something against using that module you can also easily make your own variant:

```javascript
function objEach(obj, f, scope){
    for(var key in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            f.call(scope, obj[key], key);
        }
    }
}
```

For arrays there is already dojo.forEach() in the base library.

Comment: Hey, it's you! Thanks for pointing me to the dojo irc channel. I suppose this is what I am looking for. Why is it hidden so deep in dojox? Should really be part of the core, don't you think?

Comment: That module has some extra funtionality so you can use a string instead of a function and so on. The base forEach and the custm-function (that I use) just receive plain functions.

Comment: Does `forIn` do a check of `hasOwnProperty()`?

Comment: @Sam007: I don't remember but it shouldn't be hard to check the source code or test it yourself...

Comment: i m a newbie. where do I look for the source code? how do I test it myself?

Comment: This is kinda old but I'm answering @Sam007 question for future reference, `forIn` doesn't check `hasOwnProperty(key)` instead it checks `!(key in empty)` where `empty = {}` (https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/1.9/lang/functional/object.js#L56) which it's not (always) the same and depending on your object it may or may not do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @gonz. I did realize that `forIn` does not support `hasOwnProperty` but was not sure why. This helps

Comment: @WebDevie: The link rotted. I checked and the function is still in the same place (dojox/lang/functional) in 1.9 but they apparently changed how they handle permalinks so I don't know how to fix it. If someone could do that for me I'd appreciate it.