# Dojo Equivalent for Object.keys

Tags: javascript, dojo

In the same way that dojo has array functions that provide forEach and map functions to older browsers, does the Dojo Toolkit offer a solution for Object.keys and Object.values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you iterate over an object (associative array) in Dojo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676561/how-can-you-iterate-over-an-object-associative-array-in-dojo)

Comment: It is a possible duplicate, but that answer's link is out of date and it just covers `forIn`. This question is asking specifically about `keys` and `values`.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to iterate over an object, that wasn't the point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you might be looking for `dojox/lang/functional/object`, which contains methods to get an object's keys and values. Since [the documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/lang/functional/object.html#dojox-lang-functional-object) is pretty lacking, [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/RugsZ/).

```
require([
    'dojox/lang/functional/object'
], function(o) {
    var obj = {
        key: 'value1',
        name: 'myName',
        numeric: 1,
        'hello': 'there'
    };
    console.log(o.keys(obj));
    console.log(o.values(obj));
});
```

There are also functions to `filter`, `map`, and iterate each attribute in (`forEach`) objects in that module.

Comment: Wow, that is some undercovered documentation.  The implementation seems pretty naive and doesn't make use of Object.keys where available, but it is exactly what I asked for.  Thanks.

Comment: I've found that `dojox` is not, in general, well documented. I also think that particular implementation is rather old and was written before `Object.keys` existed in most modern browsers. Glad this was what you were looking for though.